# Links inside JS code not prefixed with SCRIPT_NAME gunicorn

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am hosting a flask application on a machine where there are different flask applications, on different ports. In front of them there is nginx which act as a reverse proxy so that depending on the url prefix it redirects the requests to the proper port (i.e. application).
So for instance all requests to `my_ip/app1/..` are redirected to `my_ip:port1` and so on.
My flask app is running via gunicorn.
I have set the `SCRIPT_NAME` variable to `app1`, all the links inside the app are relative links and they do not contain the prefix *app1*, but this is automatically added and they work fine.

The problem is that this does not happen with the get and post ajax requests which I make via jquery.
Initially the urls in these requests were just the relative paths, like `distribution?a=1..`, then I replaced them with `{{ url_for('distribution') }}?a=1..`, but nothing changed.
I don't understand why `url_for` adds the prefix for instance to the links to the css and js file in the head and not to these links inside the js code.
I hope there is a better way than harcoding the prefix, which would make the code less portable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end solution was pretty simple, just use `url_for('main.get_distribution')`, so specify the name of the function associated with the route.
In this way the SCRIPT_NAME prefix is correctly prefixed to the url